# Erase element from jQuery's "plain text" html

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a following javascript **string**:

```
var string = '<div id="div1"><div id="div2"></div></div>';
```

Can I use **jQuery** to produce the following string?

```
var newString = '<div id="div1"></div>';
```

In other words, something like:

```
string.find('#div2').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup, just wrap it with the jQuery function:

```
$(string).find('#div2').remove();
```

Even though this is pointless - It doesn't actually remove the `<div>` from the string, it removes it from the newly created jQuery object, which isn't assigned to anything. If you wanted to append `#div1` somewhere you would want to assign its jQuery object to a variable before removing it's inner `<div>`:

```
$string = $(string);
$string.find('#div2').remove();
$('body').append($string);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/jsD9f/)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the inner HTML to empty string:

```
$(string).html('')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = '<div id="div1"><div id="div2"></div></div>';
var newString = $(string).empty().get(0);
console.log(newString);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dkU5Y/)**